# lib64ncurses5:The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

When I tried to install lib64ncurses5 in my ubuntu, I got this error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib64ncurses5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib64ncurses5:i386 : Depends: lib64tinfo5:i386 (= 5.9-4) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libc6-amd64:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Normally apt-get can resolve the dependency and install all the required package. So why it fails in this case.

`uname` output:

```
Linux server001 3.5.0-39-generic #60~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:38:41 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: tried to 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f' ?

Comment: No. The command is in the question: "sudo apt-get install lib64ncurses5"

Comment: did you try to perform the command i said in order to fix your problem?

Comment: Tried. Same result

Comment: then if it fails to repair itself, its up to you to solve the dependencies. google for those packages on a repository that is compatible with your distro.